# Can't read from tempfile in Python

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am trying to use some temporary files in an little python script and running into problems while using the tempfile-module:

**test-code**

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    print temp.name
    temp.write('Some data')
    print temp.seek(0).read()
```

**output**

> s$ python tmpFileTester.py
>
> /var/folders/cp/8kmr4fhs4l94y8fdc6g_84lw0000gn/T/tmpcDgrzF
>
> Traceback
>
> (most recent call last):   File "tmpFileTester.py", line 5, in
>   
>       print temp.seek(0).read() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

--> This happens on my MacBook with MacOS 10.9 and Python 2.7.5, it also happens with "delete=False".

Any ideas? It's probably a noob-error, but I can't find the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are chaining methods in Python and you get this, you can bet that one of them returns `None` (even if implicitly by not returning at all). The solution is generally to split up the chain over multiple lines.

```
temp.seek(0)
print temp.read()
```

Comment: Yeah - on somedays I really feel slow. I tried everything, but this. Thanks a lot! I'll accept this answer as I saw this one first and it solved my problem.

Comment: Don't worry! I answered in general this way because this pattern has bitten me numerous times in Python. There's something I feel like I should be able to chain, but some method along the way returns `None`, and I have to (IMO) needlessly break it up. Glad I helped!

Answer (score 2):

[`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) returns `None`.

You should separated following statement:

```
print temp.seek(0).read()
```

into two statements:

```
temp.seek(0)
print temp.read()
```

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you  explain your comment.

Comment: Sorry, it's a reference to a common English phrase "Great minds think alike". We posted nearly exactly the same answer at the same second. :)

Comment: Yeah - on some days I really feel slow. I tried everything, but this. Thanks a lot! I'll accept Two-Bit's answer as I saw that one first and it solved my problem.